Using Measure Value as a if condition in another measure?
I'm working with a 2gb semantic model and I was hoping to avoid creating a calculated column for the sake of performance.  Appreciate you guy's help in advance.
We are a large retailer with 1,000 stores.  I'm like to create a measure that will do a distinct count of the offices that archieved Net Income greater than > 15%.
I have the following data table that looks like the following:

and Net Income % is calculated using the following:
NOI% Measure =
VAR Revenue=Calculate(sum(Amount),Attribute="Revenue")
VAR NetIncome=Calculate(sum(Amount),Attribute="Net Income")

Return
Divide (NetIncome,Revenue,0)

What I'm trying to achieve is a measure that will give me an Store Count, if NOI % is greater > 15%  (nicknamed Performing Store)
I can achieve this using calculated columns.  However, there are 12 months x 10 years x 1000 stores.. I'll need to create a new table and it will add massive size to my table and increase lag.
Is there a way I can write  a measure, using a filtering criteria from another measure?
In my example above, something like this:
Performing Store Count = 
calculate(DistinctCount(StoreNumber),filter(NetIncome%>.15))  ?

My apologies if my example is not making sense.

You can use a Measure in a FILTER condition.
It could look like:
Performing Store Count = 
  CALCUALTE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[StoreNumber]),
    FILTER(
      'YourTable',
      [NOI% Measure] > 0.15
    )
  )

